# Editable drop-down in jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a requirement where the name of the patient will be searched by the doctor.

There may be multiple patients with same name as well, so when he starts searching he must get a drop-down list of all the patients with matching names he has typed.
He must be able to select from it and he must be still able to type new new search and drop down must change.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). In particular, [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) (Combobox) looks like what you are trying to do.

Comment: It appears this does not allow you to add new items.

Comment: @SVilcans You could modify `_removeIfInvalid` to add the new item instead, however `autocompletechange` is only triggered on blur, so you'd have to add event listeners for enter key and the like. `autocompleteresponse` and `autocompletesearch` events might be of use.