# Is there a Jquery plugin to replace the select tag which lets users type in their own option?

Tags: jquery, plugins, select

I'm looking for a jquery plugin to replace the html select input. It should behave in the same way as the regular select, but also contain a textbox allowing the user to enter in their own option.

For example, imagine this were valid markup:

```
Favorite fruit:
<select>
  <option value="op1"> Apples </option>
  <option value="op2"> Bananas </option>
  <option value="new"> other: <input/> </option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's usually called a Combo box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use jQueryUI's [autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) to hack something up which behaves similarly, for example:

```
var fruits = ["apples", "oranges"];
$("input").autocomplete({
    source: fruits,
    minLength: 0
}).autocomplete("search", "");


Select preset from list or type something: <input type="text"/>
```

[**Play with it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/RKpej/2/)

Comment: I've used this in the past for this purpose and it worked great!

Comment: I can probably make this work. Although in all of these answers the textbox is used to filter the drop-drown options. In my application, the textbox should only be used when none of the drop-down options are suitable. Something like the way gmail labels used to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is  the [editable combobox](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jEC) plugin.

Or do you mean something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712867/editable-dropdown-in-jquery) whose answer points to [this demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox)?  It come close, at least, to what you are talking about.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. In my case though, the textbox should simply allow the user to define a new option in case the none of the drop-downs apply. Something like gmail labels.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [flexbox](http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox) before, and it works pretty well for me. It allows typing of answers, like the jQuery UI autocomplete does, but also allows the standard dropdown box selection methods. The result forms can also be customized to show more complicated results. There's a really neat demo present in the download that allows searching for countries and displays the flag of the countries next to the name in the result set.