# Anyone know of a jquery plug-in for creating a select with a text input that appears for some choices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I.e. a regular select, but when I choose "Custom", a text input appears, and I can use that instead, as in this crude drawing:

```
 [Choice A ^]
```

becomes

```
 [Custom   ^] ____________
 [Choice A  ]
 [Choice B  ]
 [Choice C  ]
```

I can build it, but it's a common pattern....

**Note:** I'm not talking about a combo box.

Comment: How is that different from a ComboBox? Like the examples seen here: http://stuff.rajchel.pl/jec/demos/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a Jquery plugin to replace the select tag which lets users type in their own option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419548/is-there-a-jquery-plugin-to-replace-the-select-tag-which-lets-users-type-in-their)

Comment: a combo box generally lets you type into the same space as the select, and usually the option to type is always there. I want my users to have to specifically select "Custom" and then type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trickier part here is, that presumably you want the `input` and `select` box to both use the same name, so whatever is processing the form data, won't have to wonder what was selected, but instead just read the value from the one and same name.

My take on this:

```
var i;
var b = false;
$("select").change(function(){
    if($("option:selected",this).hasClass('custom')){
     i = $('<input />').attr('name','values').insertAfter(this);   
         }else{
          $(i).remove();   
         }
});

$('form').submit(function(e){
    if (!b){
   e.preventDefault();
    if ($(i).length>0){
     $('select').remove();  
    } else{
     $(i).remove();   
    }
     b = true;
    $(this).trigger('submit');
}

});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Cq59K/ (have a look at the form submission data, uses same name for fields, and doesn't have duplicate entries i.e. combo box and input box).